# lower case model endpoints (user instead of User)

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'd like my REST API endpoints to use all lower case letters for the model.

In the case of the built-in `User` model, would I simply make a new model named `user` with `User` as the base? or is there another method I should use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. At the moment, the endpoint name is case-insenstive, i.e., /api/users and /api/Users both work.
2. You can customize the model endpoint name in the model definition json, for example

   "http": {"path": "/my-users"}
3. There are a pending PR: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/433
4. As Simon pointed out, you can subclass the User model. Please the default endpoint name is derived from the plural of the model name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just generate a new model using `slc loopback:model user`, follow the prompts, then change the `base` property value from `PersistedModel` to `User` in `common/models/user.json`.

I have an example here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L3

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to set `normalizeHttpPath` setting to `true` in your `/server/config.json` file.

```
...
"remoting": {
  "rest": {
    ...
    "normalizeHttpPath": true,
  },
},
```

When `normalizeHttpPath` is set to true, it converts (in HTTP paths) from:

- Uppercase letters to lowercase.
- Underscores (_) to dashes (-).
- CamelCase to dash-delimited.

For example, "MyClass" or "My_class" becomes "my-class" in HTTP path.

Note: It does not affect placeholders (for example ":id").

For more information, look at the [remoting properties](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/config.json.html#remoting-properties) in official documentation for `config.json`.